# macOS: get full path of parent directory when parent and current directory have spaces in pathnames

Tags: shell, path

I'm trying to get a pathname into a variable in a macOS shell script, but I've been having problems with paths that have spaces in them. This shell script works correctly in a directory that has a space in its name, but produces a `zsh: operation not permitted` error when I run it in a directory that has a space in its name and also has a space in its parent's name (like this: `/Users/myname/Desktop/One Dir/Two Dir`) I've spent hours trying to sort this out with no success. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "`dirname $0`"
echo "$(cd "$(dirname -- "$1")" >/dev/null; pwd -P)/$(basename -- "$1")"
```

I've tried many other methods found in this forum and elsewhere with no success.

Comment: In your question there seems to be a combination of bash and zsh. Which one are you _actually_ using?

Comment: Thank you for catching this. All my scripts use `#!/bin/bash` and this script worked correctly in higher-level folders with that string in the first line. But when I changed it to `#!/bin/zsh` the script worked correctly in all levels. Thank you! I should have seen this earlier.